# While searching the location, getting nil response to some addresses on Google Map Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

I integarated google map in my project with Swift 4 while searching the location using SearchController and hit url to get the coordinate to that location getting nil response to the some addresses and some addresses give right response. I don't know why its happening, please help me if any one knew about this problem. Thanks in advance

Here is my code that i uses in didSelectMethod of tableView to get the coordinate to the address(in string format).

```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    // 1
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    // 2
    let urlpath = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(self.searchResults[indexPath.row])&sensor=false".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    let url = URL(string: urlpath!)
    print(url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // 3
        print(data!)
        print(response!)
        do {
            if data != nil{
                let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
                let result = dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray
                print(result)

                if result.count != 0 {

                let lat =   (((((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "lat")) as! Double

                let lon =   (((((dic.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "lng")) as! Double
                // 4
                self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(lon, andLatitude: lat, andTitle: self.searchResults[indexPath.row])

                }else{

                    print("Data Not Found")
                }
            }

        }catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
    // 5
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an API key is missing in your request. The API key is now mandatory and Google is deprecating keyless usage. Right now requests without API key are blocked for certain amount of time, in the future keyless access will be blocked completely.

> Beginning June 11, you’ll need a valid API key and a Google Cloud Platform billing account to access our core products.

source: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html

You should create an API key following the documentation and use it in your https request:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Be also aware that API keys for web services support only IP address restrictions, so you should send web service requests from intermediate server in order to protect an API key and pass response back to your iOS app.

Have a look at the following document regarding API key restrictions

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help @xomena .